# z-index not working on fixed div

Tags: css, html, fixed

So i have a website with a header and a navbar. The effect i'm trying to achieve is that the navbar lays behind the header and  then slides out when scrolling past the header. [Example](http://brochmann.se/brochmann-v0_1_2.html)

But the links wasn't clickable in the example above (they got covered by the header), so i redesigned a bit and got a successful result. But now the navbar stays on top of the header. I tried changing it by z-index, but with no success, and i have no idea what is wrong.. [Example 2](http://brochmann.se/brochmann-v0_1_3.html)

(the links are server archives, won't be changed.)

Sincerely,
a confused dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed your code in your first exmple, now it's working fine:

```
#Nav {
position: fixed;
background-color: #F0F4C3;
width: 100%;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10000;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #AFB42B;
height: 50px;
margin-left: -8px;}
#Pic {
    height: 300px;
    /*changed*/
    z-index: 100001;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    /*added*/
    position: relative;
}
```

You have to add `position:relative` to the elements using `z-index` make the `z-index` work

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

Add `position:` to `#headimage` in the css.

My bad guys :).